# To find a smooth planar curve starting at $\vec{r_0}$ stopping at $\vec{r_1}$ with some additional constraints.

Tags: optimization, vectors, curves, tangent-line, parametrization

To find a smooth planar curve starting at $\vec{r_0}$ stopping at $\vec{r_1}$ whose unit tangents at start and stop are $\hat{v_0}$ and $\hat{v_1}$ and has the minimum  length. Let us assume that the curve is $\vec{r(t)}=x(t)\hat{x}+y(t)\hat{y}$ parametrized versus $0\leq t\leq1$ having the length $L$ to be minimized:
$$L=\int_{0}^{1} |\vec{r'(t)}|dt=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}dt$$
where $$\frac{x'(0)\hat{x}+y'(0)\hat{y}}{\sqrt{x'^2(0)+y'^2(0)}}=\hat{v_0},$$
$$\frac{x'(1)\hat{x}+y'(1)\hat{y}}{\sqrt{x'^2(1)+y'^2(1)}}=\hat{v_1},$$
$$x(0)\hat{x}+y(0)\hat{y}=\vec{r_0},$$ and
$$x(1)\hat{x}+y(1)\hat{y}=\vec{r_1}.$$
Also: $$\hat{v_0}\times(\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_0})\bullet\hat{v_1}\times(\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_0})<0$$
Any idea how to minimize the $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw a picture using very small parts of the curve satisfying the initial and final conditions, it should be obvious that you can connect those parts (after appropriate turns) with a straight line segment, hence the length of the curve can be made arbitrarily close to the distance between the initial and final points.

It follows that there is no minimum length unless each of the two given unit tangent vectors are in the direction of the displacement vector, but that would break the specified dot product condition.

Comment: Yes I added a new constraint regarding the direction of the unit tangents with respect to the displacement vector from start to stop.

Comment: @Aria: My answer allows for arbitrary initial and final unit tangent vectors.

Comment: @ quasi: Can we make the small end parts of the curve sufficiently small so that $L$ is the same as the length of the linear segment connecting start and stop while satisfying the unit tangents conditions at the endpoints?

Comment: @Aria: Given your dot product condition, the length of any such curve will always be strictly greater then the distance between the initial and final points, but can be made arbitrarily close to that distance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanations!